# Hours in NSDate every time in 24-hour style?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have this date formatter:

```
 NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

If I use this:

```
 NSDate *myDate = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"13:00"];
```

It returns this:

```
 "1:00"
```

This is because the simulator has switched off 24-hour. But for my app I really need `"13:00"` instead of `"1:00"`

--- **EDIT 1** ---

Added new code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *timeForFirstRow = [timeFormatter dateFromString:@"13:00"];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:timeForFirstRow];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour]; //This will be 1 instead of 13
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are displaying the "return"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to force it to 12-hour or 24-hour mode, regardless of the user's 24/12 hour mode setting, you should set the locale of the date formatter to en_US_POSIX (for 12-hour), or, say, en_GB for the 24-hour mode.

That is,

```
NSLocale* formatterLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease];
[timeFormatter setLocale:formatterLocale];
```

Some more on that here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1480.html

Comment: really great solution! I got frustrated once. thnk god i found this.

Comment: here we hard code locale, instead  refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722309/nsdateformatter-time-format-depending-on-locale

Answer (score 9):

I had this same issue recently and came across this document which lists all the date format patterns: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

I was able to get 24-times working just by using k:mm as the date format:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"k:mm"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to two steps here

```
NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

here a in the formatter gives am/pm format

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), the time formatting strings follow [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

As stated in UTR #35, uppercase `HH` gives you 24-hour style time while lowercase `hh` gives you 12-hour style time.

In short, if you need 24-hour style, use `[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];` and if you need 12-hour style, use `[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];`

Comment: According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13): "In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set."

Comment: @Patrick, yes this is true, if I set my device to 12 hour the time returned is in 12 hour.

Comment: This is the best answer, as you don't have to spoof the location.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I have just had an issue where I want to display the time for the user in the way they have set on their device:

```
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
//get the time from the picker
```

The send the time to our API in 24 style:

```
timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
//get the time again
```