# iOS: Display time in 24-hour format if locale appropriate?

Tags: ios, time, locale

My iOS app is going to display the current time. How do I determine whether the user's locale prefers 12-hour or 24-hour time formatting?

Comment: Please, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5283539/793475

Answer (score 1):

See the NSDateFormatter class http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Something like:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to figure out what the user's locale settings are when displaying data to the user. If you use the relevant `NSFormatter` (`NSNumberFormatter` for numbers and `NSDateFormatter` for date and time, which is the relevant one for you in this case), then you will automatically get the output that is appropriate to the user's locale... i.e what Apple calls the "[localized representation of the object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i)"